# What does Array.prototype.join.call do in the background for a string?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = "foo";
var c = Array.prototype.join.call( a, "-" ); // 'f-o-o'
```

How does the second line of code work? I don't see any conversion of the string to an array and then converting back again, is this happening in the background? I've encountered this kind of code and it's very weird, an array method accepting a string.

Comment: NB: Array methods like splice(),reverse(),sort() etc. which modify the array in place will NOT work for strings because strings are immutable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string is an Array like object, because it has the property `length` and you can access its elements (chars) using `[]`  as of that you can apply most of the array manipulation operations on it.

The [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) calls the function given function with using the first parameter as `this` and the flowing one as *normal* parameters.

As of that  `Array.prototype.join.call(a, "-")` will call the function `join` on the object `a` in you case the string.

Answer (score 5):

See the [specification for `Array.prototype.join`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.join) *(below)*. It doesn't require that the `this` it's operating on be an array, merely that it have a `length` and properties with names like `0`, `1`, and so on. Strings do, and so `join` can work on a string.

From the spec:

> NOTE 2 The `join` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its `this` value be an `Array` object. Therefore, it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

Here's the full algorithm from the spec:

1. Let *O* be [ToObject](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toobject)(**this** value).
2. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*O*).
3. Let *len* be [ToLength](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tolength)([Get](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-get-o-p)(*O*, `"length"`)).
4. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*len*).
5. If *separator* is **undefined**, let *separator* be the single-element String `","`.
6. Let *sep* be [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tostring)(*separator*).
7. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*sep*).
8. If *len* is zero, return the empty String.
9. Let *element0* be [Get](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-get-o-p)(*O*, `"0"`).
10. If *element0* is **undefined** or **null**, let *R* be the empty String; otherwise, let *R* be [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tostring)(*element0*).
11. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*R*).
12. Let *k* be `1`.
13. Repeat, while *k* < *len*

    1. Let *S* be the String value produced by concatenating *R* and *sep*.
    2. Let *element* be [Get](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-get-o-p)(*O*, [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tostring)(*k*)).
    3. If *element* is **undefined** or **null**, let *next* be the empty String; otherwise, let *next* be [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tostring)(*element*).
    4. [ReturnIfAbrupt](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-returnifabrupt)(*next*).
    5. Let *R* be a String value produced by concatenating *S* and *next*.
    6. Increase *k* by 1.
14. Return *R*.

Comment: Is this for all non-destructive array methods? For example: https://gist.github.com/dare05/1feabb110d24676167b3 also can work with a string. It seems that at the beginning, it does an internal .split('') before applying the function to each string.

Comment: @daremkd: Most of the array methods are intentionally generic. Many methods on other built-in prototypes are as well. If you search the spec for "intentionally generic" (they're very consistent with their phrasing on this :-) ) you'll find a *bunch* (including `Array.prototype.map`).

Comment: @daremkd: See also the "array-like objects" part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 3):

String is array-like object. An array-like object provides indexed access to elements and the property length.  You can read more [here](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/)

Comment: Yes but a string does not behave like an array in a sense that strings are non-mutable and arrays are. Thus, is it possible to use all nonmutable array methods on a string?

Comment: You can use mutable methods(push, sort, reverse...), but string will not change its value. And, of course,  you can use any nonmutable methods

Comment: @daremkd: ...because `str = "123"; str[0] = 'x'; console.log(str);` shows `123`, not `x23`. Even `str = new String("123"); str[0] = 'x'; console.log(str);` does. Assigning to a string's index-style properties is a no-op, those properties aren't writable.